# Не видит matplotlib в sublime text 3

Tags: python

Я установил matplotlib с помощью anaconda prompt. Хорошо, в анаконде установился. Но в сам системный питон не хочет никак (pip) и когда написал в питоне уже import matplotlib, то он мне ответил:

> import matplotlib
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Хотя в анаконде он его видит и хорошо устанавливает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Что нужно сделать, чтобы его установить через pip или какие то решения для того, чтобы этого не было?

Comment: Вы на скриншоте написали в питоне уже import matplotlib, и у вас всё отлично импортировалось и работает. В чём проблема-то?

Comment: @andreymal дополнил вопрос

Comment: Вы установили matplotlib не в системном питоне, а в анаконде — вот в анаконде и запускайте.

Comment: @andreymal мне нужно установить в системный, когда пытаюсь через pip то вылезает постоянно огромная ошибка! Поэтому я думал если через анаконду то проще будет

Comment: @quicky,попробуйте еще раз установить через пип.А потом вашу "огромную ошибку" сюда выставить )

Comment: Ну так надо разбираться в причинах огромных ошибок, а не бездумно анаконды тащить.

Comment: @Raharasomaha поправил вопрос

Comment: @quicky,если вам не трудно.Отправьте вашу ошибку текстом а не скриншотом.Ибо искать ошибку с скриншота очень не удобно.

Comment: Какая у вас версия Windows и какая у вас версия Python?

Comment: @andreymal win64, python 3.8

Comment: Во-первых, Python 3.8 ещё не выпущен и matplotlib не поддерживает его, поэтому удалите его и ставьте Python 3.7. Во-вторых, ставьте 64-битную версию Python 3.7, потому что нет никакого смысла использовать 32-битную. И уже после этого пип отработает без проблем (не забудьте запустить его от имени администратора)

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. И вправду matplotlib не поддерживает 3.8 версию питона. Напишите ответ, я его приму :)

Comment: Не надо связываться с анакондой вообще.Надо ставить все что нужно через пип.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начать стоит с того, что есть два способа установки Python-пакетов: можно взять и установить собранный whl-пакет, а можно собрать его самостоятельно из исходников. Если whl-пакет есть на PyPI, то pip просто его скачает и установит; если же нет, то будут скачаны исходники, и запустится процесс сборки. В зависимости от сложности проекта сборка может состоять из простого копирования файлов, а может требовать подключения сторонних компиляторов и прочую муть и занимать часы.

На момент написания этого вопроса разработчики matplotlib [не предоставили](https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib/3.1.1/#files) собранных пакетов для Python 3.8:

[image]

В таком случае pip скачивает исходники `matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz` и пытается запустить сборку.

Процесс сборки требует Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0, freetype и прочие радости жизни — ошибка pip сообщает вам о том, что вы забыли установить какой-то требуемый для сборки компонент.

Решить проблему можно разными способами:

- Прочитать [инструкцию по сборке](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) и установить все требуемые компоненты — есть некоторый шанс, что соберётся и заработает.
- Найти неофициальную сборку для Python 3.8 и установить её. Но, кажется, такой сборки нет — даже в Anaconda лежит сборка только для Python 3.7.
- Смириться с тем, что Python 3.8 ещё не поддерживается, удалить его и установить Python 3.7 — тогда pip скачает с PyPI существующую сборку `matplotlib-3.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` и без проблем его установит (нужно запускать pip от имени администратора, чтобы установить для всех пользователей, или без прав администратора с опцией `--user`, чтобы установить только для текущего пользователя).